# Custom Clickable Image

Tags: image, custom

I've been using Craft CMS for a while, but haven't seen any way to get the following done:

Looking to create a page with a large image on it. The image would be overlayed with buttons that pop-out a text box or overlaid image. I'd like to place the pop-out boxes/graphics all over the image in specific places, but the creation interfaces I've seen only let me put one image after another in a list, or rectilinear fashion. 
I'm hoping to create a map of a neighborhood where clicking on different buildings/elements pops out another window with more information regarding that area/element.

I hope this is understandable, if more clarity is needed please let me know.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a mixture of things that work together.
Backend wise you could add a matrix field for adding multiple text or images, inside of each would be a couple of extra entry fields for X & Y placement according to where you want it on the image e.g TextBox1 would have 20% from left, 70% from top.

Comment: Getting them working in your template is more CSS specific. In your template you'll grab the X & Y's for each block in your matrix and use them as inline CSS properties on absolute positioned div's over the background image. Making them 'pop' when buttons are clicked would be some custom javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this mainly seems like a front-end development question, and Dr_Codswallop has perfectly summed up some steps in the comments to tackle that, as an answer for the Craft CMS specific side of the question there is a plugin I have used in the past that is very helpful, but it is only for **Craft 2.x**:

[Donkeytail](https://github.com/simplygoodwork/donkeytail-plugin)

I have had a look through the [plugin store](https://plugins.craftcms.com/) and I can't find an alternative plugin for **Craft 3.x**, so it looks like you will need to follow Dr_Codswallops instructions and build up something manually if you are running this version of Craft.

Comment: Cool, this looks like what I could use. Do you know if I can do more than just dots, add pop-ups with text/graphics? Or group multiple dots so that they all light up if I roll over one of them?